# print specific div using css and window.print() display on second page in pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

my problem is that i am trying to print specific div using css and jquery but printout display on second page of pdf how can i prevent that i want to printout that div from first page not to 2nd one
i have using below css

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print{
        body * { visibility: hidden; }
        #divToPrint3 * { visibility: visible; }
        #divToPrint3 { position: fixed; top: 0px; right: 10px; }
    }
</style>
```

and also print button html is

```
<a id="doPrint"  href="javascript:window.print()">
    <button class="btn btn-theme" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
        print
    </button> 
</a>
```

please give me solution, Thanks in advance

Comment: can u be more clear please? you want to show print window on same window??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: none;`, `visibility: hidden;` just hides the elements, where `display: none;` doesn't render the elements.